# Images not loading from sub directories of document directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

HI,

I am loading images from sub directory of document directory. Here is the code.

```
 NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"images/category/%@", element.image]]];
```

My images resides at DocumentDir/images/category/img1.png, DocumentDir/images/category/img2.png, DocumentDir/images/category/img3.png .....

However when images are at DocumentDir it loads fine. But when it is in sub directories like above it does not load. Am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue. There was a new line character at the end of the "element.image" variable.

Comment: how did you sove this problem?

Comment: Same as my question code. Just have used wrong value there. That code works.

Answer (score 0):

NSString *docPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"images/category/%@", element.image]];

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: docPath];

use this, One more thing image file should contain the .png or .jpg. It is required when you use the imageWithContentsOfFile method.

Comment: Still that issue exist. I logged the path and it is "/var/mobile/Applications/24355A61-C0AA-44A2-AD15-0088E0E387D4/Documents/images/category/img1.png" However when I logged the UIImage reference it returns nil so it imply that the UIImage is not properly constructed.